# How to test a controller method that uses a custom parser in play 2.5?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

My controller method:

```
def postCategory = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
    Ok("")
  }
```

and this is my test:

```
val result = categoryController.postCategory.apply(FakeRequest())
      status(result) mustEqual OK //error this line
```

I have this error:

> Error:(63, 14) type mismatch;  found   :
>   play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator[akka.util.ByteString,play.api.mvc.Result]
>   required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
>         status(result) mustEqual OK
>                ^

It seem that using a custom parser `parse.*` makes it returns `Accumulator` rather than `Future[Result]`

I'm using play 2.5-RC2

Comment: You're right about `Accumulator`. Check this out https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Writing-a-custom-body-parser

Answer (score 4):

You do should use result.run getting instance of Materializer with Guice

would look like:

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
//...

def mockApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build()
val mtrlzr = mockApp.injector.instanceOf[Materializer]

val result: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = controller.accessToken()(FakeRequest())
val runResult: Future[Result] = result.run()(mtrlzr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with something like this:

```
  val result = categoryController.postCategory.apply(FakeRequest())
  status(result.run) must equalTo(OK)
```

It basically looks like Accumulator has a nice `run()` method that returns a `Future`.

Comment: the `run()` method requires an `implicit materializer: Materializer` input. It's quite strange to me as didn't have to do this in play 2.3. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My guess is Play 2.5 made the big move towards Akka Streams for anything that has to be done asynchronously. Akka Streams says here [http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#stream-quickstart-scala] "The Materializer is a factory for stream execution engines..."

Comment: i had the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036803/play-framework-test-helpers-need-implicit-materializer