# Play Framework test helpers need implicit `Materializer`

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-http

I'm using Play 2.6.x and the test helper for `status(result)` has the method:
`def status(of: Accumulator[ByteString, Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer): Int = status(of.run())`

Running tests throws when the compiler can't find the implicit value:
`could not find implicit value for parameter mat: akka.stream.Materializer`

What is the Materializer -- I'm assuming it's part of Akka-HTTP

And how can I provide one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From akka streams [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html):

> The Materializer is a factory for stream execution engines, it is the
> thing that makes streams run [...]

The `Materializer` is the cornerstone of Akka Streams, on which Akka HTTP is built on. You need one of these to be implicitly resolved to make your test compile.

Presently the `ActorMaterializer` is the only available implementation of `Materializer`. It is a `Materializer` based on Akka [actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala#actors). This is the reason why, to create one, you need in turn to have an `ActorSystem` in scope.

The following code is what you need in your test:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
implicit val sys = ActorSystem("MyTest")
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
```

Comment: Stefano - I am doing this but I am getting NoMaterializer exception when I run my test case. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577155/getting-unsupportedoperationexception-nomaterializer-does-not-provide-an-execu

Answer (score 2):

there's also a status method in the form:

```
def status(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout): Int
```

make sure the controller return type is correct so the action returns a `Future[Result]`

Comment: i tried this -- it still required the Materializer in order to produce a `Future[Result]` using `controller.method().apply(FakeRequest()).run()` unless you know some other way?

Comment: yes, try `controller.method()(FakreRequest())` no need apply or run

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this:

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

Comment: awesome thanks! this worked but i still needed to add an implicit `ActorRefFactory` within scope using as @stefano mentioned above `implicit val sys = ActorSystem("MyTest")`

Answer (score 1):

As of Play 2.6.0 `ActorMaterializer()` is deprecated, but you can do this instead:

```scala
 val as = ActorSystem()
 implicit val materializer = Materializer(as)
```